# How to perturb a spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory

Suppose we have some vacuum spacetime, described by the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ which is a solution to Einstein's field equation $G_{\mu \nu} = 0$. For concreteness, let's just suppose I have some M = 1000 $M_{\odot}$ black hole.

Now if I introduce some star ($m = 1 M_{\odot}$) around this black hole, the mass of the star will perturb the spacetime and we can write for small perturbations,

$$ \bar{g}_{\mu \nu} = g_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$$

where $h_{\mu\nu}$ describes the perturbation introduced by the star.

**My question is**, how do we determine the actual vaule of $h_{\mu \nu}$? I can see potentially substituting $\bar{g}_{\mu \nu}$ back into the Einstein field equations, but is this still a vacuum case such that $G_{\mu \nu} = 0$, or else should we consider some small perturbation to the stress energy tensor, i.e. $G_{\mu \nu} = 8 \pi \delta T_{\mu \nu}$?

Comment: Well, generally, you should write down Einstein's equation $\tilde{G}_{\mu \nu} = \tilde{T}_{\mu \nu}$ and throw away all terms of higher order in $m/M$ than 1. This should give you a good enough approximation.

Comment: If you want a star, then you should put its energy momentum tensor. Of course, you might want to approximate it by a black hole, in which case you would just put zero again. In general, you need to use the appropriate tensor.

Comment: Note that in 4d spacetime Swarzschild solution is *not* a solution of EFE with delta-distribution of stress energy.

Comment: I am mainly intereseted in a spinning black hole, i.e. Kerr metric. How does this relate to the Teukolsky equation?